# How to get multiplication value from 2 tables codeigniter?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I've 2 tables in database where table 1 have 11 fields and table 2 has 10 fields. I try to multiply both of them and display into an HTML table,
. But I got the error message

> "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array".

```
    Table 1. |id| |kota_kab| |ipm| |pddmiskin| |ginirasio| |rasio_k| |indks_pend| |indks_kes| |ppk| |tpt| |tpak|

    Table 2. |idno| |maxK1| |minK2| |minK3| |minK4| |minK5| |maxK6| |maxK7| |minK8| |maxK9|
```

Here is my Model

```
class Model_data extends CI_model {
    function tampildata(){
        $hasil=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM datakota");
        return $hasil->result();
    }
    function maxmin(){
        $sql=$this->db->query("SELECT maxK1, minK2, minK3, minK4, minK5, maxK6, maxK7, minK8, maxK9 FROM maxmin");
        return $sql->result();
    }
    function coba(){
        $sql = $this->tampildata();
        $sql2 = $this->maxmin();
        foreach ($sql as $key => $isidata) {
            $hasil=array(
                'id' => $isidata->id,
                'kota_kab' => $isidata->kota_kab,
                'ipm' => $isidata->ipm/$sql2[$key]['maxK1'],
                'pddmiskin' => $isidata->pddmiskin/$sql2[$key]['minK2'],
                'ginirasio' => $isidata->ginirasio/$sql2[$key]['minK3'],
                'rasio_k' => $isidata->rasio_k/$sql2[$key]['minK4'],
                'indks_pend' => $isidata->indks_pend/$sql2[$key]['minK5'],
                'indks_kes' => $isidata->indks_kes/$sql2[$key]['maxK6'],
                'ppk' => $isidata->ppk/$sql2[$key]['maxK7'],
                'tpt' => $isidata->tpt/$sql2[$key]['minK8'],
                'tpak' => $isidata->tpak/$sql2[$key]['maxK9'],
            );
        }
        return $hasil;
    }
}
```

View

```
<?php
    $no = 1;
    foreach($data as $hasil){
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $no++ ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $hasil->kota_kab ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $hasil->ipm ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $hasil->pddmiskin ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $hasil->ginirasio ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $hasil->rasio_k ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $hasil->indks_pend ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $hasil->indks_kes ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $hasil->ppk ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $hasil->tpt ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $hasil->tpak ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: First, Try to merge both results into one array and then multiply

Comment: I've tried to combine both results into one array but still getting error "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"

Comment: what me bothers is - you iterate over your results from `datakota` and use the iteration key to get data from `maxmin` - how should this even work ? you should probably post some sample data from `maxmin` and `datakota` and show how those data are related to each other...

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching an object through `result()` and you are treating foreach `$isidata` data as an object then why not `$sql2` data. You can try :

```
foreach ($sql as $key => $isidata) {
    $hasil=array(
        'id' => $isidata->id,
        'kota_kab' => $isidata->kota_kab,
        'ipm' => $isidata->ipm/$sql2[$key]->maxK1,
        'pddmiskin' => $isidata->pddmiskin/$sql2[$key]->minK2,
        'ginirasio' => $isidata->ginirasio/$sql2[$key]->minK3,
        'rasio_k' => $isidata->rasio_k/$sql2[$key]->minK4,
        'indks_pend' => $isidata->indks_pend/$sql2[$key]->minK5,
        'indks_kes' => $isidata->indks_kes/$sql2[$key]->maxK6,
        'ppk' => $isidata->ppk/$sql2[$key]->maxK7,
        'tpt' => $isidata->tpt/$sql2[$key]->minK8,
        'tpak' => $isidata->tpak/$sql2[$key]->maxK9,
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank for help my problem, but I've already tried code like that you post before, but the error still same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function coba(){
    $sql = $this->tampildata();
    $sql2 = $this->maxmin();
    $result = array_merge($sql, $sql2);
    foreach ($result as $key => $isidata) {
      $hasil=array(
        'id' => $isidata->id,
        'kota_kab' => $isidata->kota_kab,
        'ipm' => $isidata->ipm/$isidata->maxK1 //Do this
       );
    }
```

**Note:-** But make the columns performing mathematical operations should same in number

Comment: Thank for help, the error became "Undefined property: stdClass::$maxK1". What I've to do sir?

Comment: Try this `print_r($result);` and check whether `maxK1` exists or not

Comment: maxK1 already exist but how to get value of that in looping array. Can you tell me to fix it. Sorry of my bad english.

Comment: '[5] => stdClass Object ( [maxK1] => 90 [minK2] => 7.47 [minK3] => 0.42 [minK4] => 50 [minK5] => 0.76 [maxK6] => 0.83 [maxK7] => 15991 [minK8] => 7.01 [maxK9] => 70 ) )'
the result above print at the last index

Comment: No no. use `print_r($result)` before foreach loop

Comment: yes, use `print_r($result)` above foreach, before looping. I've tried to uncomment my foreach loop and just check merge array with `print_r($result)` but the result showing that

Comment: First, just check whether all the columns exists in an array that are using in the loop or not.